# From: Set of sets. To: Family of sets.

Tags: set-theory

Consider a family of sets $(A_i)_{i\in I}$. This is just a short-hand notation for a mapping $I\rightarrow X$, where $X$ contains all sets ${A_i}$ (the notation $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ of course omits to give the information about the range of the function it represents).
Then we an easily form $\{A_i : i\in I \}$, which isn't a mapping anymore, but a set, namely the set of all sets $A_i$.

Now consider going the other way: Let $T$ be as set and $\mathcal{T}\subseteq 2^T$  a subset of the powerset of $T$.
*What $\textsf{ZFC}$ axioms do we need to apply, to show that sets $I,X$ and a mapping $f:I \rightarrow X$ exist (this mapping doesn't have to be unique of course), such that for each $\hat{T}\in\mathcal{T}$ there exists a $i\in I$ with $f(i)=\hat{T}$?* This effectively would show that give a set of sets, we can turn it into a family of sets.

Comment: What is $\cal Y$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Corrected (Make self-note not to change notation midsentence and forget about it.)

Comment: BTW .A  MathJax "function" like \mathcal and \cos  , when applied to a single key-stroke, does not require brace-brackets. E.g. \mathcal T , \cos x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every set is indexed by itself. So you only need to prove that the identity function exists.

That depends on how exactly you're formulating a function, i.e. how you're coding ordered pairs, and whether or not a function equals to its own graph, etc.

But in general, the formula $\varphi(x,y)$ given by $x=y$, applied to $\{A_i\mid i\in I\}^2$ is enough, so now we reduced this to the existence of a Cartesian product and the simplest Separation axiom. For Cartesian products, in their simplest (read: Kuratowski) coding, you'll need Power Set (normally union and pairing as well, but here we only care about $X^2$ for some set $X$).

Of course it goes without saying, Extensionality is always needed to ensure that everything operates as it should.